# Impact of holidays on forecast with statsmodels package

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, state-space

I am fitting an Unobservedcomponents model from the statsmodels package to a time series. To add the impact of holidays I one-hot encoded a bunch of holiday dates to be passed as an exogenous matrix.
When comparing the forecasted output with and without the holidays, I expected the difference to be only on the holiday dates, but in addition, I notice that the level and trend coefficients have also changed. I am not sure why should that happen.
Please see the figure below - the red line is the forecast with the holidays and blue line is the forecast without the holidays. The only difference in the model instantiation is the inclusion of holidays as exogenous variable, why then is the red line shifted a notch above the blue line.

[image]

Comment: The values of the series are lower on holidays. If that is not corrected as with the holiday dummies, then it will pull the prediction down, the parameters adjust so prediction for both holiday and non-holiday data are closer to the observed values. That's the same distortion as when we include outliers in a regression.

Comment: Yes of course that makes sense. I got confused with the output from facebook's prophet with and without holiday input where I saw that the difference was only on the holiday dates  - but that was a chance result on a specific series. Thank you for the clarification.